# How to make long press touch and hold in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to longpress to make my chat to archive.(i.e) like whatsapp we have long press and make the chat to pin in the top

How can I make the same using react-native?

Answer (score 9):

These long presses can be handled by passing a function to the `onLongPress` props of any of the `Touchable` components.

Delay in ms, from `onPressIn`, before `onLongPress` is called.

`delayLongPress`

```
<TouchableOpacity 
 style={[styles.modelView]}
 onLongPress={() => {
     console.log('Long Press')
 }}
 delayLongPress={3000}>
     <Image 
       style={[styles.modelSelection]}
       source={{ uri: 'image' }}
       resizeMode='contain'/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Here I need to show the image to pin my chat after the user clicks or touches the chat for a long time. Same as the whatsapp.

Comment: setState inside `onLongPress ` as per your requirement. get selected index and change cell according to selected index

Answer (score 2):

What input type are you using?

If you are using any of the touchable components, you can use the `onLongPress`. More info on it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches)

Comment: For example I have a wapp chat screen. I need to archive one of the chat

Comment: You will need to provide a code example. However, I would recommend you give it a go. If you are still stuck, open a new question.